# Order of multiplication in $\prod_{i=1}^n$ notation

Tags: notation

Consider the expression $\prod_{i=1}^n O_i$ in a setting where multiplication is not commutative. Is there a convention as to whether to interpret this as $O_1\cdot O_2\cdots O_n$ or $O_n\cdot O_{n-1}\cdots O_1$?

One can certainly specify this in the preamble of an article, but I am wondering if there is an established convention.

Thanks

Comment: I would expect it to be left-to-right, especially because of the situation with *infinite* products. But I still might discourage this notation in a noncommutative setting.

Comment: When writing such an expression, you may really want to clarify that in your preamble (e.g., by explicitly (re-)introducing the notation with a recursive definition $\prod_{i=1}^nO_i:=(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}O_i)\cdot O_n$)

Comment: @Ian Then again, infinite products are totally different beasts. I always think it is a pity that the names are too similar for products (as opposed to "sum" vs. "series" for addition)

Comment: Thank you. I don't think infinite products make a very convincing case. For instance Dollard and Friedman define the product integrals, denoted still by $\prod_{a}^b$, as the limit of finite products performed right to left!

Comment: I cannot find a link to the book itself, but here is a review which outlines their notation https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0013091500004259