# Notation: Using $\prod A_i$ for noncommuting $A_i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, products

I am writing up some math and realized that I do not know whether $\prod_{i=1}^m A_i=A_mA_{m-1}\cdots A_1$, OR whether $\prod_{i=1}^m A_i=A_1A_2\cdots A_m$.

Is there accepted consensus on this ordering?

Comment: I would interpret the product as meaning the latter, but I do not know if there is any consensus on this.

Comment: The accepted consensus is that you define the meaning before you use it.

Comment: Personally, I would write the first product as $\;\displaystyle\prod_{i=m}^1 A_i$.

Comment: Same question without an answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949234/order-of-multiplication-in-prod-i-1n-notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly as is mentioned in the comments, the more common notation is probably
$$\prod_{i=1}^mA_i=A_1A_2\dotsm A_m,$$
but to be unambiguous, it is definitely good practice to first define your notation before using it. That is, add a line like

> We write $\prod_{i=1}^m A_i$ as shorthand notation for the product $A_1A_2\dotsm A_m$.